# Island hopping rebels

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Since 1.8, rebels are able to teleport across sea tiles, without the use of boats.

- When will they actually do that?
- How far can they jump?
- If your empire is fragmented, will the rebels walk through foreign territory, or will they magically bypass it?
- Does all types of rebels have teleporting technology?

I have a stack of Sunni Zealots on Rhodes, and one in Trebizond, while my closest territory is in Greece (or possibly Cyprus). I'm hoping for them to come to me, as I can't be bothered building a million transports just to curb stomp them, but so far they've been content just sitting where they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my experience goes:

- They have no small limit to movement distance: Either there is none, or it is large (via at least ~8 provinces)
- They will happily walk through a foreign nation's territory
- All rebels can move this way

I believe without being certain rebels take longer to start movement via sea compare to regular movement via land provinces. I could not find a pattern here yet.

Also note that rebel sea movement can be blocked by sea blockading a province with ships.

In your situation, make sure there is an unblockaded way from the islands to the mainland, and wait some time. If that does not work, either change plans and invade, or just ignore the rebellion: if too few provinces are held, it will not make progress anyway.

Comment: I have not played much in the recent time, so please feel free to correct me if I misremembered.

Comment: They have not moved at all in ~10 years. My plan was to ignore them altogether, however in the meantime I have gotten the "Religious Turmoil" disaster, and need to eradicate all rebels to get rid of it. Guess I have to build an armada of transports.